# Is there a way to group values getting only the ones that verifies certain condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to write a query in Oracle SQL that aggregates values by some ids, where I have the following table as an input:

| ID | SOME_DATE | RANK_POSITION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 20211201 | 1 |
| 301 | 20211202 | 2 |
| 301 | 20211203 | 3 |
| 649 | 20211201 | 1 |
| 649 | 20211202 | 2 |
| 649 | 20211206 | 3 |
| 649 | 20211208 | 4 |
| 649 | 20211211 | 5 |
| 758 | 20211212 | 1 |
| 758 | 20211222 | 2 |

And y want to obtain something like this:

| ID | FIRST_IN_RANK_DATE | SECOND_IN_RANK_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 01/12/2021 | 02/12/2021 |
| 649 | 01/12/2021 | 02/12/2021 |
| 758 | 12/12/2021 | 22/12/2021 |

Where `FIRST_IN_RANK_DATE`, is the date that is the first in the `RANK_POSITION` for the `ID`, and `SECOND_IN_RANK_DATE` is the date that is second in `RANK_POSITION` for the specific `ID`.

Comment: Look into `pivot` or `conditional aggregation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE rank_position WHEN 1 THEN some_date END) AS first_in_rank_date,
       MAX(CASE rank_position WHEN 2 THEN some_date END) AS second_in_rank_date
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
```

Or `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(some_date)
  FOR rank_position IN (
    1 AS first_in_rank_date,
    2 AS second_in_rank_date
  )
)
```

Or, from Oracle 12, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY rank_position
  MEASURES
    rank1.some_date AS first_in_rank_date,
    rank2.some_date AS second_in_rank_date
  PATTERN ( ^ rank1 rank2 )
  DEFINE
    rank1 AS rank_position = 1,
    rank2 AS rank_position = 2
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, SOME_DATE, RANK_POSITION) AS
SELECT 301, DATE '2021-12-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 301, DATE '2021-12-02', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 301, DATE '2021-12-03', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 649, DATE '2021-12-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 649, DATE '2021-12-02', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 649, DATE '2021-12-06', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 649, DATE '2021-12-08', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 649, DATE '2021-12-11', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 758, DATE '2021-12-12', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 758, DATE '2021-12-22', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | ID | FIRST_IN_RANK_DATE | SECOND_IN_RANK_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 301 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-02 00:00:00 |
> | 649 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-02 00:00:00 |
> | 758 | 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 2021-12-22 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=457e65431e862d46634c2d165581a361)*